# Include size "0" in Store

Tags: expresso-store

My client runs a women's clothing store where they need to enter size "0" for some of the items. However, it seems like Store interprets this entry as an empty field and does not allow it as an option in the modifier field. As a workaround we've used size "00", but I've been told that "00" and "0" are actually 2 different sizes in women's clothing.

We're running Store 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate the issue on a site that I have too, this seems like a bug or oversight in how 0 & null are handled.

You can use `0&nbsp;` or `'0  '` in the option portion to get it to work without having to use 00 which would be a different size. Inserting either an actual space or the html for a forced space will cause Store to create it as a modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in [Store 2.0.4](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_204) which was released today:

> Fixed product options named 0 being treated as empty

You can now create product options named "0" and they will not disappear or be treated as an empty string.